# Сравнивание слова со списком. Python

Tags: python

Есть список слов `[['Учитель'], ['Психотерапевт'], ['Биохимик'], ['Сексолог']]` и есть слово. Допустим `Биохимик`. Как мне сравнить есть ли `Биохимик` в этом списке или нет?

```
n = int(input('Количество игроков: '))
i=0
while n > i:
    i = i+1
    with open('Proff.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as source:
        l = source.readlines()
        word = ''
        word = l[random.randint(1, len(l) - 1)]

    with open('vibor.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        lst = [ line.split() for line in f ]


    while [word] in lst:
        word = l[random.randint(1, len(l) - 1)]
```

Comment: У вас не список, а список списков.

Comment: `'Биохимик' in itertools.chain.from_iterable(l)`, где `l` - список списков из вопроса.

Answer (score 3):

```
words = [['Учитель'], ['Психотерапевт'], ['Биохимик'], ['Сексолог']]
word = 'Биохимик'

if any(word in j for i in a for j in i):
    print('Слово есть в списке')
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте оператор `in`:

```
word = 'Биохимик'
lst = [['Учитель'], ['Психотерапевт'], ['Биохимик'], ['Сексолог']]

if [word] in lst:
    print('Да.')
else:
    print('Нет.')
```

---

*Добавления (к добавлению вашего кода в вопрос):*

1. Удалите лишнюю команду

   ```
   word = ''
   ```
2. Вместо сложного

   ```
   word = l[random.randint(1, len(l) - 1)]
   ```

   примените

   ```
   word = random.choice(l)
   ```
3. После

   ```
   l = source.readlines()
   ```

   добавите

   ```
   l = [w.strip() for w in l]
   ```
4. После

   ```
   lst = [ line.split() for line in f ]
   ```

   добавите

   ```
   lst = [w.strip() for w in lst]
   ```
5. Вместо

   ```
   while [word] in lst:
   ```

   примените

   ```
   while word in lst:
   ```

Comment: Почему-то не выходит в моем коде.
` import random

n = int(input('Количество игроков: '))
i=0
while n > i:
    i = i+1
    with open('Proff.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as source:
        l = source.readlines()
        word = ''
        word = l[random.randint(1, len(l) - 1)]

    with open('vibor.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        lst = [ line.split() for line in f ]


    while [word] in lst:
        word = l[random.randint(1, len(l) - 1)] `

Comment: А как тогда в таком случае написать код?

Comment: Добавил в мой ответ.